# How to include wxWidgets headers in CMake project

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, wxwidgets, include-path

I am trying to run wxWidget example using cmake but unable to include the headers of wxWidgets in my C++ project(CMakeLists.txt). If i run the program using the command

```
g++ main.cpp `wx-config --cppflags --libs` -o wxTest
```

the program works and display the window. But how can i do that using CMakeLists.txt file. For example, usually i create a separate folder called external-libs and then inside it create a folder with the name *whateverlibraryname* and then inside it create a header and src and lib folder where i place the header files, any source files and .so files respectively. But in the case of wxWidgets i have several static library files and also inside the header there are many separate folders and i don't know how to include them all. They produce the error:

```
fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wx/wx.h>
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and my project directory structure is as follows:

```
├── build
└── source
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── external-libraries
    │   └── wxWidgets
    │       ├── headers
    │       │   ├── msvc
    │       │   │   └── wx
    │       │   └── wx
    │       │       ├── android
    │       │       ├── aui
    │       │       ├── dfb
    │       │       ├── generic
    │       │       ├── gtk
    │       │       ├── gtk1
    │       │       ├── html
    │       │       ├── meta
    │       │       ├── motif
    │       │       ├── msw
    │       │       ├── osx
    │       │       ├── persist
    │       │       ├── private
    │       │       ├── propgrid
    │       │       ├── protocol
    │       │       ├── qt
    │       │       ├── ribbon
    │       │       ├── richtext
    │       │       ├── stc
    │       │       ├── univ
    │       │       ├── unix
    │       │       ├── x11
    │       │       ├── xml
    │       │       └── xrc
    │       ├── lib   
                ├── libwx_baseu-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_aui-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_html-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_propgrid-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_qa-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_ribbon-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_richtext-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_stc-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwxjpeg-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwxregexu-3.1.a
    │       │   ├── libwxscintilla-3.1.a
    │       │   └── libwxtiff-3.1.a
    │       └── src
    ├── main.cpp
```

**Main.cpp** has `#include<wx/wx.h>` at the top. I am using VSCode and when i ran the program using g++(command described above) it works but doesn't workwhen i run the same program using CMake. That is how to include the header folder and use the lib folder that contains all the wxWidgets headers and library files. What should be the contents of the CMakeLists.txt files and what are the other necessary things that i have to do to make this work.

Comment: Please edit your question with your current (attempt at) CmakeLists.txt

Comment: Have you seen this? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html

Comment: @Botje I use the add_library() command to add the external library and then target_include_directories() to include the headers and then target_link_libraries() to link. This works for other external c++ libraries but is it possible to do with wxWidgets?

Comment: @JasonLiam Yes. It boils down to creating an `INTERFACE` library and linking the `.a` files to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake has first-party support for wxWidgets, here's an example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(wxTest)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

add_executable(wxTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wxTest PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

It's a bit unfortunate how legacy this module is. The above code would be much better off using imported targets and not need to do this weird dance with `include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})`, but alas. At least it's documented.

There are various variables you can set to help it find your wxWidgets installation. See the documentation for more details: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html

Comment: Is that a typo in next-to-last line? `add_executable(wxTest main.cpp)`? Also, I can't believe this worked. :) Thanks. It's definitely a long way from `\`wx-config --cppflags --libs\``

Comment: @JohnC - it is a typo -- fixed. I also can't believe how far off this is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the prior answers too theoretical and short on examples, like much of CMake.

My issue was adding WxWidgets, to an existing CMake system, on Ubuntu 22.04.

Problem - CMake does escape the "`" in `wx-config --cxxflags`

Solution - run

wx-config --libs

from a command line, copy the output and replace `wx-config --cxxflags` with it.

IN MY SPECIFIC CASE, not yours, it was

-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u-3.2

Do the same for

`wx-config --cxxflags`

IN MY CASE

-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread

The final snippet that worked was this

```
set(WX_FLAGS "-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread")
set(WX_LIB_FLAGS "-L/usr/local/lib -pthread -lwx_gtk3u-3.2")
list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${WX_FLAGS} -fPIC ${WX_LIB_FLAGS}")
```

Since the hard coded options are invariant over an installation of WxWidgets on a single machine, they should be stable until you modify the installation of WxWidgets.

A more portable solution is to execute the wx-config and capture the result in a variable.

```
execute_process(COMMAND wx-config --cxxflags OUTPUT_VARIABLE WX_FLAGS OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
execute_process(COMMAND wx-config --libs OUTPUT_VARIABLE WX_LIB_FLAGS OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

Be sure to strip trailing whitespace or there will be a <CR> in the middle of your call to the compiler.