# CMake failing to link wxWidgets

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, include, wxwidgets

I am trying to link wxWidgets to the [Hello World example](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html) and it fails when I build with `cmake --build build` after `cmake -B build`. It seems to be a linking / include directory problem.

I am using the subdirectory method from the [here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2.2/overview_cmake.html), but I've also tried the `find_package()` method from [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html) (as well as other methods online). The source tree contains a wxWidgets folder, CMakeLists.txt, and main.cpp.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)

add_subdirectory(wxWidgets)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test wx::net wx::core wx::base)
```

When I try to build, it errors with:

```
C:\...\main.cpp(2,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wx/wx.h': No such file or dir
ectory [C:\...\build\test.vcxproj]
```

I have a version of wxWidgets in C:\libs\ **and** in the [project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJypc.png). This is because I'm originally using the C:\libs\ version, but I want to change this so the project can be independent. When I use the other method with `find_package()` from [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019574/how-to-include-wxwidgets-headers-in-cmake-project), it will find a different version of wxWidgets on my computer and error with:

```
MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_m
ain(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) [C:\...\build\test.vcxproj]
C:\...\build\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\...\build\test.vcxproj]
```

I would prefer to use the subdirectory method. I want to build wxWidgets with the project. I've also found different solutions that have varying degrees of success but the result is a mess of a build tree or errors with different build configurations.
[source tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJypc.png)

Comment: [How to include wxWidgets headers in CMake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019574/how-to-include-wxwidgets-headers-in-cmake-project)

Comment: @user12002570 Thank you - but I try this in the 2nd part of my question and it results in the above error.

Comment: *"it will find a different version of wxWidgets on my computer"* Different from what? How do you know it's different?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have a wxWidgets in the project directory as well as in my machine libs folder. The goal is to make the project self contained rather than relying on the dev to have wxWidgets installed. Maybe having the 2nd version is messing something up? I will edit the question.

Comment: I *think* `find_package` should be better, but you need to specify a path to your own wxWidgets (usually from the command line) to use it instead of the system-wide one, but I'm not exactly sure which flag should be used.

Comment: But fixing the first approach is probably easier, pass the subdirectory with the headers to `target_include_directories`.

Comment: I tried `target_include_directories(test PRIVATE wxWidgets/include/wx wxWidgets/include/msvc/wx)`and it resulted in the following errors: https://pastebin.com/huJ1j5Rg

Comment: @Marco, please check the minimal sample directory. It contains the CMake configuration file you can use to build the library.

Comment: @Igor, This is working, thank you. However it doesn't work for Release build, only Debug. I will look into it.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")` fixed the release issue.